# Use ansible output for set_fact with loop maybe

Tags: ansible

I use ansible for create and run lxc containers in proxmox.
Run container task:

```
    - name: "DHCP IP"
      proxmox:
   ...
        hostname: "{{ item }}"
   ...
        pubkey: "{{  pubkey  }}"
      with_items:
          - "{{ (servers_name_suggested | union(servers_name_list)) | unique }}"
          register: output_dhcp
          when: not static_ip

    - set_fact:
        vmid: "{{ output_dhcp.results[0].msg | regex_search('[0-9][0-9][0-9]') }}"

    - name: "Start container {{ vmid }}"
      proxmox:
        vmid: "{{ vmid }}"
        api_user: root@pam
        api_password: "{{  api_password }}"
        api_host: "{{  api_host }}"
        state: started
      when: start_lxc
```

It's work if launched one container, one item in task "DHCP IP". If I set
two or more item, my task started only first container. Because I am setting

```
output_dhcp.results[0].msg
```

How I can take information about all containers, as example, if I will create tree containers:

```
output_dhcp.results[1].msg
output_dhcp.results[2].msg
```

and received to

```
- name: "Start container {{ vmid }}"
  proxmox:
    vmid: "{{ vmid }}"
```

for run all my new cotainers.

Comment: The output_dhcp variable should contain all the values inside the stdout_lines. Can you do a debug instead of set_fact on the var output_dhcp and not on output_dhcp[0]

Answer (score 1):

The `output_dhcp.results` is a list, if you extract only the first item with a `[0]` you will only have the first item.

You need to transform the list into another list you can iterate over in the "Start container" task:

```
- set_fact:
    vmids: "{{ output_dhcp.results | map(attribute='msg') | map('regex_search', '[0-9][0-9][0-9]') | list }}"

- name: "Start container {{ item }}"
  proxmox:
    vmid: "{{ item }}"
    api_user: root@pam
    api_password: "{{ api_password }}"
    api_host: "{{ api_host }}"
    state: started
  with_items: "{{ vmids }}"
  when: start_lxc
```

To explain the transformation part:

- `output_dhcp.results | map(attribute='msg')` => get the `msg` attribute of each item of the `output_dhcp.results` list (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map)
- `| map('regex_search', '[0-9][0-9][0-9]')` => apply the `regex_search` on each item of the list
- `| list` => transform the generator into a list

Comment: Not bad but I have got error

`    "item": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f132c0abb90>", 
    "msg": "starting of VM <generator object do_map at 0x7f132c0abb90> failed with exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<generator object do_map at 0x7f132c0abb90>'"
`

Comment: Should be fixed by adding `| list` (answer updated)

Comment: Now I have got message on set_fact stage:
`
list indices must be integers, not str"}

`