# Search by owner with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to list all files of a directory with the owner of the file her name start with 'a',
i have a ansible playbook like this

```
- name: Recursively find 
   find:
    paths: "/tmp"
    age: "6d"
    age_stamp: ctime
    file_type: any
    patterns: "*"
    recurse: no
   register: output
```

Comment: The [`find_module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) does not have a parameter or capability for ownership yet.

Comment: But it seems the result will have an attribute `pw_name` over which one could loop and filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*List all files of a directory with the owner of the file her name starts with 'a'.*"**

A: For example, given the tree

```sh
shell> tree -u tmp
tmp
├── [admin   ]  file1
├── [admin   ]  file2
└── [user1   ]  file3
```

Find all files in the first task and select the owner in the second task

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: tmp
      register: output
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.path }}"
      loop: "{{ output.files|selectattr('pw_name', 'match', '^a.*$')|list }}"
```

give

```yaml
  msg: tmp/file2
  msg: tmp/file1
```

Comment: Interesting solution. However, I've got an error `Invalid data passed to ''loop'', it requires a list, got this instead: <generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7fae12d51f50>`. Maybe I need to [transform the generator into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55040623/6771046) before.

Comment: Right, use the ``list`` filter. I'm not sure why it's working for me (2.10, 2,11, python version = 3.8.5, jinja version = 3.0.1) without this filter. I updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: this works fine for me but i needed this line at the end of the debug:
with_items: "{{ output.files }}"