# Ansible set_fact output

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I need the string or destination path as the output and use it in other task but the output displayed is dfifferent.
Here is the register output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "checksum": "b045e5836bbd01d9c6dd2b7426afb5d1c8957b30",
                "dest": "/home/ec2-user/bb/Data-1.1.tar.gz",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_original_basename": null,
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backup": false,
                        "checksum": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "dest": "/home/ec2-user/bb/Data-1.1.tar.gz",
                        "directory_mode": null,
                        "follow": false,
                        "force": true,
                        "group": null,
                        "local_follow": null,
                        "mode": null,
                        "owner": null,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "remote_src": true,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": "/home/ec2-user/aa/Data-1.1.tar.gz",
                        "unsafe_writes": null,
                        "validate": null
                    }
                },
                "item": "/home/ec2-user/aa/Data-1.1.tar.gz",
                "md5sum": "df9309334454cc3ceac9a6ac8fea8989",
                "src": "/home/ec2-user/aa/Data-1.1.tar.gz"
```

I used the below the task to display the destination path

```
     - set_fact:
          filefact: "{{ output.results | map(attribute='item') | string }}"
     - debug:
          msg: "{{ filefact }}"
```

The output displayed is

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f59539f01e0>"
```

Comment: According [use Ansible output to `set_fact` with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010263/) you may need to ransform the generator object into a list via `| list` instead of `| string`.

Comment: Changed string to list output is : fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'output' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/setfact3.yml': line 13, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n       register: file\n     - set_fact:\n       ^ here\n"}

Comment: How would you like to use the "extracted" file path, i.e. which other task needs this (please update question)?

Comment: Want to take the dest path and pass it as variable to the next task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd write :

```
 - set_fact:
      filefact: "{{ filefact | default([]) + [output.results.item] }}"
 - debug:
      msg: "{{ filefact }}"
```

the right syntax , following your output should be:

```
- set_fact:
    filefact: "{{ filefact | default([]) + [output.results[0].item] }}"
```

or

```
- set_fact:
    filefact: "{{ filefact | default([]) + [item.item] }}"
  loop: "{{ output.results }}"
```

Comment: The output is displayed is : ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "/home/ec2-user/aa/DataFeed-1.1.tar.gz"                                                                                      How to take the set_fact output  as a variable and pass it to other task

Comment: filefact[0] is your value